Chase pipes behind lath and plaster
I have a colonial built in 1900.  The copper pipes for heating and tap water are corroding as I have repaired one pin-hole leak and it's only a matter of time before things start to fail rapidly.  I intend on using a home run system for my water supply and my radiator heat system.
Can I chase all those pipes between the lath and plaster and the brick wall?  I have enough room to stick my hand between the brick and the lath.  Can I just run the pipes up this gap?  Or does that break code in the event someone wants to nail/screw/hang something from the wall?
I want to do this right and not screw this up for my family or whomever buys this house from us in the future.


Are you asking if you can relocate all those pipes behind the wall facing?  Is that an insulated wall?

Im not entirely sure.  The two bays to each side have, I think, the original insulation (burlap? bags filled with something?).  If not insulated, I know I can't do it, but then I wonder, what would I need to do to then be able to chase the pipes.  Basically, what do I need to do to make the pipes disappear?

I would think you could build basically a box around them.

Yeah...you are right...I brought it up to my wife and she asked why I can't put it in a box next to the main stack which is literally two feet to the left edge of my picture.

Always listen to your wife, even if you end up doing something different.
